# SVN: Prevent a newer client from upgrading a working copy's SVN version?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to prevent a newer SVN client (say 1.6) from automatically upgrading a working copy that was checked out with an older client (say 1.4 or 1.5)?

I find that as soon as I touch a working copy with a newer client, anyone using an older client to work with the same files can no longer do so (for obvious reasons).

Assuming requiring everyone to upgrade their SVN clients isn't an option, is there a configuration setting or flag I can set to prevent my newer client from making this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480629/svn-prevent-a-newer-client-from-upgrading-a-working-copys-svn-version/2480648#2480648) is misleading — there is nothing wrong with using multiple client versions on the same *repository*; the problem you're describing arises when multiple client versions are being used on the same *working copy*.

So unless the same *person* is using multiple clients (which could certainly happen, e.g. command line client + TortoiseSVN), it shouldn't be a problem to not have every person upgrade their clients.

To directly answer your question, no it is not possible to prevent auto-upgrading of working copies, but it *is* possible to undo it after the fact.  See [the release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#wc-and-fs-format-change) for a Python script that will accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems counter-intuitive to me that you have multiple *people* using the same *working copy*. Having multiple clients is one thing (for example, I have AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN that access my working copies) but having multiple *people* using the same working copy is - to me - not the normal way SVN should be used.

I would say the "ideal" solution would be to give each person their own working copy, and then let them use whatever client version they like.

Comment: I have already seen wicked configurations like this: One WC on a shared directory with everyone working on that WC. It will fail every now and then and sometimes kill your work. So everyone should have their own WC!

Comment: @Hardcoded A working copy in a shared directory?!  That gives me chills.  And not the good kind.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a repo with multiple client versions is not recommended for this reason! You can [set access permissions](http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/usage/svn-govern-commit-permission.html#Commit+Permission+Governance%3A+Example) per user and use different clients on your local machines with different SVN users.